# iOS - Saving current user - are Keychain and saving to disk mutually exclusive?

Tags: ios, keychain, nskeyedarchiver

I want to save a current user of my application, but I’m a bit confused on how I choose between what’s necessary for the keychain and what should be saved to disk or even if both or just one should be used.

I’m thinking I should save the user’s email and password to keychain, then save the user object (comprised of email, password, name, gender, and uuid) to disk (minus the email and password)

Is this the correct approach? Or should I be doing something else

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the data you wish to store is tiny: why not store it all in the keychain? It won't be more effort, and will in the end prove simpler than storing half on disk and half in the keychain. And if the user has keychain sync activated, you benefit from that for free...

Comment: Maybe, but this approach doesn’t seem very expandable for the future. Also, isn’t keychain meant for secure data like email and password? Storing a name here seems inappropriate

Comment: Then stick to email and password only, adding UDID so that you can store info on disk based on UDID alone: privacy guaranteed, and not too much junk in the keychain.